# Unknown: Failed opening required '0ff' (include_path='.:/tmp:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, linux

I got the following errors today.I did not any changes to my PHP program.

> Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   Unknown on line 0
>
> Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '0ff'
>   (include_path='.:/tmp:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in Unknown on
>   line 0

....after a few hours...server admin says at his point of view 'there is no problem'!

what a nice solution :))

Now, after a few hours the error changed to the following message

> Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '0ff

```
; As of 4.0b4, PHP always outputs a character encoding by default in
; the Content-type: header. To disable sending of the charset, simply
; set it to be empty. 
; 
; PHP's built-in default is text/html default_mimetype = text/html 
;default_charset = iso-8859-1 
; Always populate the $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA variable. 
;always_populate_raw_post_data = On 
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; 
; Paths and Directories 
; 
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; 
; UNIX: /path1:/path2 include_path = .:/tmp:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php
; 
; Windows: \path1' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php') in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Please provide code which fails with this error

Comment: That's a misinterpreted config setting somewhere. Note that the wrong value is `0ff` and not `Off` (Zero where an Oh should be).

Comment: yes.. you right.. it should be off and not 0ff

Comment: Expanded the quote. It's not formatted verbatim from the source any more, but it's now legible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Unknown on line 0` usually indicates a configuration error, so talk to your sysadmin. Also, the value in the error message (`0ff`) seems like "Off" but it actually begins with a zero - most probable cause of the error.

Comment: Ok, i contacted to server support and still waiting for their reply or action. and you right.. it should be off and not 0ff

Comment: Right, so the following data from the INI file is being treated as a path.

Comment: i found the problem...i used phpinfo() on my website and it showed me server PHP configuration. Then i search for '0ff' and found the following line at php.ini om my server

`auto_append_file    0ff`

and it is obviously is the point of the error. '0' instead of 'O'
let me contact the server admin and tell him about the error.

Thanks to all

Comment: This is part of an exploit involving a file called 0ff which is created in your /tmp folder. But this file has allready been removed causing the errors. Your probably should remove /tmp from your include path.