# .htaccess Rewrite - Fails if file exists with the same name as parameter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have been having a little trouble with a rewrite rule which, after Googling around led me nowhere. I have a standard rewrite of a URL setup like this:

```
RewriteRule ^services/(.*)/ /services/index.php?content=$1 [L]
```

The site uses the value of `content` to request the related content from the DB but just makes the URL look prettier; standard stuff. This works to a certain extent. If, for example, my URL us `/services/testimonials/` the rule works fine; the content gets loaded and the page displays normally. What I was seeing with some URLs though (e.g. `/services/training/`) was an error stating:

```
Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0 Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'redirect:/services/index.php' (include_path='[removed]') in Unknown on line 0
```

After much Googling and head banging (with little progress from either) I discovered that if I changed the URL to `/services/Training/` (notice the capitalised T) it worked. This quickly led me to a thought about a conflict in the URL with something (which I probably should have thought of first in hindsight). After checking which URLs worked and which didn't, I connected the dots and found the URLs that were broken had files with the same name in subdirectories the same as the URL. That sentence is confusing. Basically I cannot use the URL `/services/training/` as there is a file `/services/training.php` which causes the return of the error.

There is an obvious fix to this which is to rename the files that conflict with the URLs, but is there a way in the rewrite rule where I can get it to ignore any files it may find of the same name?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722846) will help you? As the accepted answer in that question states, `Line 0` usually indicates a server configuration error, because you are getting an error from PHP before it has started to execute a script. Note that you are getting PHP errors, not Apache errors, which suggests that PHP is getting fired up by Apache.

Comment: Thanks @DaveRandom, the issue solved was slightly different to the one I'm having although it being a PHP error makes sense.

Comment: Have you tried redirection without appending the previous path as a variable? You can anyway read it in `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']`.

Comment: Sorry @Ranty I don't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: You can use `RewriteRule ^services/.* /services/index.php [L]` and then in index.php you get the requested url by looking at `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']`

Comment: Thanks @Ranty but it still results in the same error. The set up is failing before I even hit the PHP page because of the conflict between the URL and the existing file names.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Options -MultiViews
```

This should prevent the url from mapping to training.php. It will however not prevent `/services/training.php` from not mapping, but that won't be a problem I presume.

Comment: The simplest answers are always the best. Thanks @Gerben

Comment: +1 I can't believe I had forgotten this. Some years ago it took me a while to get started with `mod_rewrite` for this very reason.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario It funny how many times I posted this one line of code as a solution to a problem.

Comment: What is that? Something to add to .htaccess?

Comment: @nafg You indeed need to add this line to a .htaccess file.